# How to change flex-direction on a mat-grid-tile?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I just can't figure out how to change the flex direction on mat-grid-tile..

I want to display 3 components in a grid-tile and they are all stacking left to right instead of being displayed nicely from top to bottom.

It's probably just that simple but I can't find the proper way to do that..

I've tried

`mat-grid-tile { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }`

but it doesn't work, can you help me pls ?

i can't use the cols attribute either because it's already in a grid, and it doesn't work to put a grid in a grid. Here's my page for better understanding :

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2">

  <mat-grid-tile>
    <app-admin-about-me></app-admin-about-me>
  </mat-grid-tile>

  <mat-grid-tile>
    <app-admin-projects-list></app-admin-projects-list>
    <app-admin-skills-list></app-admin-skills-list>
    <app-admin-tools-list></app-admin-tools-list>
  </mat-grid-tile>

</mat-grid-list>
```

and I'd like to display as a column the second tile

Comment: Alternatively you can create your own container - the Grid List component doesn't actually use Flexbox nor does it use CSS grids.

Comment: that's what i've done, thx mate !

Answer (score -1):

mat-grid-list  has cols property you can use it show all tiles in a single column. Overiding css using flex won't be much helpful.

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="2:1">
  <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>4</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: I edit my question to explain why cols attribute doesn't fit